Can't connect ubuntu server to WAN on static ISP
PROBLEM: I was able to install ubuntu server 20.04 on brand new bare metal machine via ISO usb, but dont get any WAN connection, depending on the ISP feed. It does connect to the LAN, just not getting out to the WAN. In the volunteer fire department communications center where I volunteer, I have available to me two fiber static ISPs, and one non-static LTE ISP. I have NOT been unable to connect to the WAN on the two static ISP feeds. It will connect to the WAN on the ISP with the LTE non-static feed.  I have tried setting up a spare router to one of the static ISPs and same issue. I need to resolve his since the final setup needs to be on one of the static ISPs.  It is clearly specific to the static ISP provision.
I am using the server desktop GUI and its networkmanager interface, although I can use the command prompt.  I have looked through posts with similar issues, but usually the answers are not on point to actually solve my issue, or over my experience level. I am hoping this is pretty simple as I am admittedly very notice ubuntu user/volunteer.  Not professional.  Thanks

Is there any reason why you didn't start off with Ubuntu 24.04?  What happens when you boot up from the USB and use Ubuntu off the USB.  If you try to get a DHCP connection, are you successful?  If you diagnose your problem by removing cases (even if they are obvious), it will make it easier for people to help you.  Your ISP feed is coming through a modem/router?  Can you check its configuration and confirm it's not blocking your server?

This is a repeat of the question you asked a few hours ago and have since deleted. That is not how this site works. If there was more info to add you edit the question not delete and repost. You had comments asking you several questions on the deleted post, they were not answered.

David.  Thsi is my first time on this site.  Have a little patience while I learn the etiquette.  I was told to separate the two part question into two separate questions, which I did.

What is not working? How is things configured right now? You write that LAN works; I guess this implies DHCP? How is WAN to be configured? How have you attempted to configure it?

The reason I am using 20.04 is that the app it will serve is a special fire alarm industry app that is UL regulated and ubuntu server 20.04 is the highest version so far approved.

"What is not working," is the WAN on the two static ISP feeds.  Yes, all three methods connect to the LAN via the routers DHCP server.  But on the two static ISPs, that is where it stops.  No WAN.  I have set the static IP WAN IPv4 statically as it has always been and works for a number of other Windows PCs on those feeds. Same static IP, subnet mask, and Gateway settings.  I did attempt setting up a Vlan and didn't help. Exact same. I will try to printscreen those settings and post for clarity. And yes, have done a lot of experimenting including a new spare router from default. Same symptoms.

What doesn't work?

Thanks for everyones comments.  I did solve this issue, and it was nothing to do with the server settings, it was a router setting.  It took me a while because, as is obvious, I am two days old with my first Ubuntu (or an Linux flavor) and had to crash coarse myself to even learn how to see my way around.  We are using a Peplin Max BR1 router which has two WAN feeds and two LAN ports.  One WAN feed is static IP ethernet.  The other is automatic failover to cell LTE WAN.  I had set up a Vlan on the port 2 but had the port type set to Trunk instead of Access.  Now works on both WAN feeds.
